# Vim Syntastic проверка во время редактирования

Tags: vim

Сейчас плагин `syntastic` проверяет после сохранения. Можно ли проверять по мере набора кода?

Comment: логично будет поискать ответ в документации к этому вашему *plugin-у*.

Comment: судя по документации на плугин - такой возможности нет. И это логично - плугин использует возможности компиляторов/интепретаторов по проверке валидности. Запуск любого интерпретатора и проверка синтаксиса - это не секундное дело. А виму, что бы обеспечить заданный функциона придется сохранять буфер на каждое нажатие и запускать чекер. А задерки даже по 0.05 сек между нажатиями будет сильно раздражать.

Comment: @KoVadim, я думаю, ваш комментарий вполне тянет на полноценный ответ.

Comment: возможно, но ответ был бы "нет" и его пришлось бы добивать пробелами:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из комментария:

---

судя по документации на плугин - такой возможности нет. И это логично - плугин использует возможности компиляторов/интепретаторов по проверке валидности. Запуск любого интерпретатора и проверка синтаксиса - это не секундное дело. А виму, чтобы обеспечить заданный функционал, придется сохранять буфер на каждое нажатие и запускать чекер. А задержка даже по 0.05 секунды между нажатиями будет сильно раздражать.